# formatting part of text inside a textfield

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

Suppose you have a text-field in your webpage. The value inside text-field is "This is your welcome text". Is there any way by which I can provide red color to "welcome" and not to other words.

In short applying styling on some part of text inside a text-field.

can some body suggest a way of doing it?

Comment: yes I meant <input type="text"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a text field. You could use a `div` or some other element with `contentEditable` set

```
<div contentEditable="true">
This is your <b style="color:red";>welcome</b> text
</div>
```

However there are caveats depending on what you want to do with that text.

Comment: Oops. Changed the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible unless you are using some sort of [rich text editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), etc But again I don't think it will be worth incorporating a rich editor for such minor task.

Comment: I am trying to implement some kind of dictionary search so that when you type a wrong word in the text-field, the word turns red instead of providing red-border on text-field. I tried appending text-nodes as child of the text-field but those go as it's innerHTML instead of becoming its value.

Comment: @alter: As I said, you can't turn a simple text field to show multiple colors for different parts of text unless you use some sort of rich text editor like i showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do any styling in a `<textarea>` except CSS styles that applies to all text inside it.  What most rich text editors do is programmatically replace the textarea with an iframe with `contentEditable` set to true.  The way they go about it to make it seamless is relatively advanced and complex, but can be done.

I would recommend just using an off-the-shelf rich text editor for your needs, but if you want to make your own there are plenty of [resources available](http://www.google.com/search?q=writing+a+javascript+rich+text+editor).

Answer (score 1):

RoToRa's right, except you need to use TRUE, not yes.

The below code works. You will have to style it more to make it look like a textbox.  In Firefox, for example, when you click it, an ugly border appears around it.  But this is something like what you want.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width:200; border:1px solid black; padding:1.5;">
This is your <b style="color:red";>welcome</b> text
</div>
```

Try using CSS to style it instead of using an inline style.  Since you have lots of textboxes it would be better that way.  I just did it using an inline style to give you an idea of how you can make it look more like a textbox.  Border and a slight padding.  And then you'll also need to make it some sort of scrollable div.  But that's a different question.