# Dynamically modifying TextField value - Javascript - change color

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically modifying a textfield using Javascript by adding some extra character (say X). For this I use:

```
document.forms['Form1'].elements['some_field'].value = document.forms['Form1'].elements['some_field'].value + "X";
```

But can I change the color of "X"? Like have it insert (say) a Red colored "X".

Comment: possible duplicate of [formating part of text inside a textfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460270/formating-part-of-text-inside-a-textfield)

Comment: *Just* the `X`? I don't believe so. You could put something *next* to the field, though.

Comment: Yes. Essentially I am adding some noise to the textfield and want it to be displayed in a different color. @Felix: I think this is different, since I am adding text dynamically using JS.

Comment: It's still not possible ;) Whether the value is static or dynamic does not matter.

Comment: @Titan How it *gets* there isn't really relevant, I just don't think you can do that with a text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `contenteditable` span and make it look like a text box.

HTML:

```
<span contenteditable="true" id="main"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "<span style=\"color:red\">X</span>";
```

(optional) CSS Styling

```
#main {
    appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    height: 20px;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TnUQW/